How to factor out duplication code Haskell ( Maybe & If-Else)

the fruit is a Maybe type
if fruit is a apple and it is sweet (test with function testSweet) ,then trigger process A
if it is not sweet or fruit is Nothing, then go with process B

Here is the dummy code,
   case fruit of 
       Just apple ->
           if testSweet apple then 
               <ProcessA>
           else
               <ProcessB>
       Nothing ->
               <ProcessB>

But it looks duplication here , any way to fix this ? I think the optimal way there should be only one <ProcessB> in the code.

You can match on maybe False testSweet fruit = True, or testSweet <$> fruit = Just True, or fruit = Just (testSweet -> True) if you like ViewPatterns.

Just to be sure, Just apple doesn't test if the fruit is an apple; it just ensures that fruit is not Nothing and calls whatever is wrapped apple for purposes of testing if it is sweet. If you are literally trying to differentiate apples from pears, for example, something else needs to be done.

You can use a guard and a catch-all fallback:
case fruit of 
   Just apple | testSweet apple ->
      <ProcessA>
   _ ->
      <ProcessB>

The last case _ will match both Nothing and Just non_sweet cases.

You can use Maybe's Foldable instance:
if any testSweet fruit
then <ProcessA>
else <ProcessB>

However, unlike the pattern match in the other existing answer, you will not have access to apple inside ProcessA. If that's needed, you could use find instead, but I'd consider this somewhat obfuscated compared to the pattern-match-and-guard way.
case find testSweet fruit of
    Just apple -> <ProcessA>
    Nothing -> <ProcessB>

